# Mail Error:- Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "support@myDomain.io" using 3 possible authenticators

Tags: laravel, email, laravel-8, laravel-mail

Google mail is running perfectly for sending mail but domain-mail (support.myDomain.io) returns following errors

`Swift_TransportException Failed to authenticate on SMTP server with username "support@xamer.io" using 3 possible authenticators. Authenticator LOGIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials o28-20020aa7979c000000b005809a3c1b6asm11901153pfp.201 - gsmtp ". Authenticator PLAIN returned Expected response code 235 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials o28-20020aa7979c000000b005809a3c1b6asm11901153pfp.201 - gsmtp ". Authenticator XOAUTH2 returned Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at 535 5.7.8 https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials o28-20020aa7979c000000b005809a3c1b6asm11901153pfp.201 - gsmtp ".`

env code :-

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=support@myDomain.io
MAIL_PASSWORD=******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=support@myDomain.io
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

controller code :-

```
Mail::to($data->email)->send(new EmailVerify($data));
```

app/Mail/EmailVerify.php :-

```
<?php

namespace App\Mail;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Mail\Mailable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;

class EmailVerify extends Mailable
{
    use Queueable, SerializesModels;

    /**
     * Create a new message instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($data)
    {
        $this->data = $data;
    }

    /**
     * Build the message.
     *
     * @return $this
     */
    public function build()
    {
        return $this->subject('Email from '.env('APP_NAME'))->view('mail.emailVerify')->with(['data' => $this->data]);
    }
}
```

config/mail.php :-

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Mailer
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This option controls the default mailer that is used to send any email
    | messages sent by your application. Alternative mailers may be setup
    | and used as needed; however, this mailer will be used by default.
    |
    */

    'default' => env('MAIL_MAILER', 'smtp'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Mailer Configurations
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | Here you may configure all of the mailers used by your application plus
    | their respective settings. Several examples have been configured for
    | you and you are free to add your own as your application requires.
    |
    | Laravel supports a variety of mail "transport" drivers to be used while
    | sending an e-mail. You will specify which one you are using for your
    | mailers below. You are free to add additional mailers as required.
    |
    | Supported: "smtp", "sendmail", "mailgun", "ses",
    |            "postmark", "log", "array"
    |
    */

    'mailers' => [
        'smtp' => [
            'transport' => 'smtp',
            'host' => env('MAIL_HOST', 'smtp.mailgun.org'),
            'port' => env('MAIL_PORT', 587),
            'encryption' => env('MAIL_ENCRYPTION', 'tls'),
            'username' => env('MAIL_USERNAME'),
            'password' => env('MAIL_PASSWORD'),
            'timeout' => null,
            'auth_mode' => null,
        ],

        'ses' => [
            'transport' => 'ses',
        ],

        'mailgun' => [
            'transport' => 'mailgun',
        ],

        'postmark' => [
            'transport' => 'postmark',
        ],

        'sendmail' => [
            'transport' => 'sendmail',
            'path' => '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',
        ],

        'log' => [
            'transport' => 'log',
            'channel' => env('MAIL_LOG_CHANNEL'),
        ],

        'array' => [
            'transport' => 'array',
        ],
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Global "From" Address
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | You may wish for all e-mails sent by your application to be sent from
    | the same address. Here, you may specify a name and address that is
    | used globally for all e-mails that are sent by your application.
    |
    */

    'from' => [
        'address' => env('MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS', 'hello@example.com'),
        'name' => env('MAIL_FROM_NAME', 'Example'),
    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Markdown Mail Settings
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | If you are using Markdown based email rendering, you may configure your
    | theme and component paths here, allowing you to customize the design
    | of the emails. Or, you may simply stick with the Laravel defaults!
    |
    */

    'markdown' => [
        'theme' => 'default',

        'paths' => [
            resource_path('views/vendor/mail'),
        ],
    ],

];
```

when I am using google mail with same code is running perfectly

```
MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=587
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail.gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=*******
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=tls
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=mymail.gmail.com
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"
```

I  am trying to send mail from my domain email (support@myDomain.com) in laravel.

I googled it a lot, but could not find a proper answer. I would be very glad if any of you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

Did you turn on the "Allow less secure apps" on? if not go to this link

https://myaccount.google.com/security#connectedapps

Look at the Sign-in & security -> Apps with account access menu.

You must have to turn the option "Allow less secure apps" ON.

If it still doesn't work try one of these:

Go to https://accounts.google.com/UnlockCaptcha , and click continue and unlock your account for access through other media/sites.

Use double quote in .env your password: "your password"

also don't forget to clear the cache

```
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: hello @karandarji This code works fine via gmail, email produces this error.

Comment: can you suggest me for email

Comment: because I have email account(domain email)

Comment: Yes, this is for the email. Is "Allow less secure apps" enabled for smtp username that you are using?

Comment: Maybe this question will help you, might be related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74897635/laravel-mail-error-failed-to-authenticate-on-smtp-server-with-username-suppor